# ng-model wont recognize value and stay undefined

Tags: angularjs

im trying to pass a variable from `<input>` to function using ng-model inside the input, but the variable stays undefined no matter what i do. the input field is inside `<td>` and looks like this:

```
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="l" ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index"  value="{{letter}}"/>
        <button class="save" ng-click="saveCron(cron_format)">save</button>
    </td>
```

and currently im just trying to display the value in the console using `saveCron()` like this:

```
$scope.saveCron = function(cronFormat){
    console.log($scope.l);
}
```

but the variable stay undefined...im guessing its a simple thing im missing but i just cant figure it out...any idea plz?

Comment: You're not passing userId and scriptId to saveCron.

Comment: missed it in the copy paste...still its not the problem

Comment: this code doesn't make much sense; what is it supposed to do that it has an ng-model and an ng-repeat on the same element?

Comment: im trying to get the value inside input after user changed it , and compare it with the value that initialized the table, and than post it if change occurred

Comment: right, but if, for example, you have 26 `letters`, you will have 26 input boxes, all bound to the same `l`.  How would that even work?

Comment: in fact, looking at it, I think if you inspected the output from the code, you would see that your `ng-model="l"` is probably replaced by the ng-repeat for each element, since the model for each element is based on the ng-repeat, so I doubt that `$scope.l` ever gets a value.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a scope inheritance issue. Try using the `controller as` syntax or just put your model onto an object. e.g.:

html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.l" .../>
```

js

```
$scope.saveCron = function(cronFormat){
    console.log($scope.vm.l);
}
```